# Using openweathermap api for free

Tags: google-chrome-extension, weather-api, openweathermap

Can I use [openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org/api)  api for free in a chrome extension?
I am trying to build a chrome extension which will use openweather map api. Can I use it for free if I want to place it on webstore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://openweathermap.org/price_detailes for more details.

> All data provided by OpenWeatherMap is distributed under terms of
>   the Creative Commons license
>   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/.
>       Under this license data can be freely used through API with non-commercial or commercial purposes.
>       However, the OpenWeatherMap name must be mentioned as a weather source in a visible part of the application.
>       For Enterprise accounts other licenses different from Creative Commons are possible. Please, send us your request